# How to unshare a Datagridviewrow

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

So I've been having issues with a Datagridview in my project, so i thought i'd boil it down the to most basic it can be and work from there up. It seems that i just don't understand what is going on with it, because

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
ThreadGrid.Rows.Add(row);
ThreadGrid.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
ThreadGrid.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Causes the error "The row provided must be unshared first".

I cannot find an "Unshare" method, or a "Shared" property in anything relevant. Am i just missing something here, or am i asking the impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some explanations about row sharing on MSDN: [DataGridViewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/c1120ta9%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) (Remarks section)

> The DataGridView control will share DataGridViewRow objects across
>   multiple data rows whenever possible to avoid performance penalties.
>   Unless you are working with large amounts of data and experiencing
>   performance issues, you can typically ignore row sharing. A shared row
>   is indicated by an Index property value of -1. Some members of the
>   DataGridViewRow class cannot be used with shared rows, but **you can
>   unshare a row by accessing it through the
>   DataGridViewRowCollection.Item** property. Rows can also become unshared
>   in other ways. To access a row without unsharing it, use the
>   DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow method. When working with large
>   amounts of data, you should be aware of how rows are shared and
>   unshared to avoid performance penalties. For more information, see
>   Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control.

So, accessing a row by its index will unshare it:

```
ThreadGrid.Rows.Remove(ThreadGrid.Rows[0]);
```

Comment: Alright, so suppose i don't know the index of the row. IndexOf() returns -1, that causes another exception to be thrown.

Comment: @user2085282, but you do: the Add method returns the index